# Laravel Unable to retrieve the file_size for file at location

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I am trying to download a file from local storage but keep getting the error: Unable to retrieve the file_size for file at location.

```
        if (file_exists($filePath)) {
            return Storage::download($filePath, $fileName);
        }
```

The file path is tested prior to make sure the file exists.
The error is being thrown from vendor/league/flysystem-local/LocalFilesystemAdapter.php line 418.

```
    public function fileSize(string $path): FileAttributes
    {
        $location = $this->prefixer->prefixPath($path);
        error_clear_last();

        if (is_file($location) && ($fileSize = @filesize($location)) !== false) {
            return new FileAttributes($path, $fileSize);
        }

        throw UnableToRetrieveMetadata::fileSize($path, error_get_last()['message'] ?? '');
    }
```

**I set a break point on the line**

```
$location = $this->prefixer->prefixPath($path);
```

**and found that $location is being set to some kind of weird concatenation of the folder path and the full file path.**

```
C:\Users\tomva\Projects\laravel\storage\app\C:/Users/tomva/Projects/laravel/storage/app/pph/482678575-0150974001684180496/1283_CO1SAL_202301_O.pdf
```

I thought maybe it had something to do with developing on windows so I uploaded to our web server which is Linux but got the same error.

I tested just getting the file size and it throws the same error.

```
$size = Storage::size($filePath);
```

But using `is_file($filePath)` and `filesize($filePath)` work fine;

Just to make sure the file could be downloaded I tried using some code from another application that I have used for downloading files and it worked fine.

Anyone know what would cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using **file path** as an argument to **storage::download()**.

The **storage::download() has already path of that directory**, you just need to pass a **name of the file that you want to download as a first argument**. The **second parameter** is the file name that **users will see on file download**.

Here is an example:-

```
 Storage::download($fileName, $userShownFileName);
```

Where **$fileName** is the **original file name** and **$userShownFileName** is the **file name for the users** on downloading. You can read more on the **[laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#downloading-files)**.

Comment: Can you tell me how to format this if the file is in /public/documents/file.xlsx and I want it to show them price-list.xlsx? Thanks!

Comment: @CasaCoding First you should use the Storage directory instead of public. Next if you want to keep the file public then there is a public folder in the Storage, place file in it. If you don't want to keep it public then don't place in public folder of Storage. Inshort you have to place it in the Storage Folder. After putting in the Storage Folder, now you can use the similar as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: so I meant like a real life example ('./folder/filename', "whatUserSeesName") but, I found a better solution to my issue.
return Response::download('./documents/file.xlsx');

Comment: @CasaCoding Yes you can use Response::download or response()->download() also. But with this function you have to use public folder path. Both options are available, you can choose anyone.  Either use Storage public folder or directly placing in the public folder. Remember that, if you use storage public folder, you have to create symbolic link to make it accessible. Which can be easily done using a artisan command. 

Anyhow, hope this information helps you.